# Regexp test YYYY-MM-DD error

Tags: javascript, regex

I can not solve the problem with regular expression, any ideas?

```
var pattern = new RegExp("/(19|20)\d\d[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/")
// regexp for test date format like YYYY-MM-DD,
data = "2013-12-20"; // Date
console.log(pattern.test(data)); //returns false
```

Sorry for the stupid question, but I'm new in regexp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using both `new RegExp(...)` and the literal `/pattern/` syntax, either drop the `/`s or the `new RegExp` and it'll work. Currently, you're also testing for `/` at the start and end of the *String*.

---

Just tested, if you write it as the literal (dropping `new RegExp` and quotes), it works. Dropping the slashes isn't working because you haven't escaped the backslashes, so they're not actually in the *String* once it's interpreted.

An example of each using the tips above:

```
var using_constructor = new RegExp('^(?:19|20)\\d\\d-(?:0[1-9]|1[012])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$');
var using_literal = /^(?:19|20)\d\d-(?:0[1-9]|1[012])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;
```

Comment: Using the RegExp constructor, you'll need to escape your escape slashes. The \ is an escapement in JS strings and in the RegExp, so to get it all the way through to the RegExp engine you have to use \\. Or use the RegExp literal and you don't need to consider that. @PaulS. feel free to add that to your answer.

Comment: I forgot to drop quotes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var pattern = /(19|20)\d\d[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/ // regexp for test date format like YYYY-MM-DD,
data = "2013-12-20"; // Date
console.log(pattern.test(data)); //returns true
```

Comment: Two notes, the square brackets around the hyphens are unnecessary, and based on the OPs example none of the parenthesized sub-patterns need capturing, so you could add `?:` just inside the open-paren.